# How to use TWTSideMenuViewController from a Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've looked at the code of various "Sliding menu" solutions and [TWTSideMenuViewController](https://github.com/twotoasters/TWTSideMenuViewController) looks to be one of the best.

The GITHUB project hasn't an example of how to use this class with a Storyboard.

1. When creating 3 views (twtsidemenuviewcontroller, main and menu) on my Storyboard what segue do I create segues between them?
2. What code do I need to add to AppDelegate.m?
3. Can I create a class for the menu view in the normal way or does TWTSideMenuViewController?

Comment: Did you find a way of doing it?

Comment: No. But on closer inspection i didn't like the UI glitch in this system when a menu option was tapped so I've written my own menu classes.